# I am not able to find maven dependency of tdmext.jar

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency

I am converting an old java project to a spring boot project.
The old project was using tdmext.jar for which I am not able to find maven dependency for that jar.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an old license protected jar file. Since you already have it available to you from the old project, what you can do is include the tdmext.jar in the resources of the Spring Boot project and use the [maven-install-plugin](https://www.baeldung.com/install-local-jar-with-maven/) to install it automatically in the local repository at the build stage.

If you have a private artifact repository at your disposal, I would recommend to go a step further and upload it there. Then you would simply refer to it as a normal dependency.